# Phone 8 XAML: Horizontal Alignment in LongListSelector

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, alignment, longlistselector

I've got a long list selector.

All I want to do is to align two elements inside the ItemTemplate:
 1. a button to the right with a given, fixed width
 2. a text panel to the left that fills the remaining space of the display.
But unfortunately the text panel is not strechted and the button is aligned to right end of text of the text panel. :(

This is my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="DummerContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and

```
<phone:LongListSelector
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      x:Name="AddrBook"
      JumpListStyle="{StaticResource AddrBookJumpListStyle}"
      Background="Transparent"
      GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}"
      LayoutMode="List"
      IsGroupingEnabled="true"
      HideEmptyGroups ="true"/>
```

So, this is my question: How can I align the two elements correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a result of using a horizontal `StackPanel`...

Use a `Grid` rather than a `StackPanel` in your DataTemplate. Then you can define the `ColumnDefinitions` to assign the space as you require, i.e.:

- define column 0 as `Width="*"` and put your `TextBlock` in it
- define column 1 as `Width="Auto"` put your `Button` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, Stackpanel is faster than Grid. So, i decided to find out the root of the problem. And i found it here: http://y2bd.me/blog/2013/08/16/fixing-alignment-issues-with-datatemplateselector/

Works fine for me.